Getting error that I am using an older version of rust, but --version shows I am using latest
Although my Rust is version 1.78.0 I constantly am getting this error when I do an anchor build:
error: package toml_edit v0.21.1 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.69 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.69 or newer, or use
cargo update -p toml_edit@0.21.1 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of toml_edit supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
I have tried everything (from clean new rust build to forcing builds) nothing works.

Does this answer your question? How do I fix "package solana-program v1.18.0 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer"?
